# How to enable WebGL on Chrome on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, graphics-card, webgl

My GPU is a NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS. [According to NVIDIA](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-8400-gs/features),

> OpenGL® 2.1 Optimizations and Support: 
>   Ensures top-notch compatibility and performance for OpenGL applications.

If I understand it correctly, that means it supports WebGL.

WebGL works on Firefox, both natively and through ANGLE. If I go to https://get.webgl.org/, it says

> Your browser supports WebGL

However, on Chrome it says

> While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable

I have checked that `Use hardware acceleration when available` is enabled and `chrome://flags/#disable-webgl` is disabled.

If I go to `chrome://gpu/`, Chrome says

> WebGL: Unavailable
>
> Problems Detected
>
> - GPU process was unable to boot: GPU process launch failed.
>       *Disabled Features: all*
> - Always call glUseProgram after a successful link to avoid a driver bug: [349137](http://crbug.com/349137)
>       *Applied Workarounds:
>     use_current_program_after_successful_link*
> - Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
>       *Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost*
> - Disable use of Direct3D 11 on Windows Vista and lower
>       *Applied Workarounds: disable_d3d11*
> - Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: [124764](http://crbug.com/124764), [349137](http://crbug.com/349137)
>       *Applied Workarounds:
>     clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use*
> - Disable D3D11 on older nVidia drivers: [349929](http://crbug.com/349929)
>       *Applied Workarounds: disable_d3d11*
> - Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: [398694](http://crbug.com/398694)
>       *Applied Workarounds:
>     scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args*
> - Raster is using a single thread.
>       *Disabled Features: multiple_raster_threads*

I tried enabling `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist`, but nothing changed.

My OS is Windows XP Home SP3. On the same machine I also have Lubuntu 15.04, and there it works if I enable hardware acceleration.

Is there a way to enable it on XP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable WebGL in my browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser)

Comment: @MC10 My problem is that Chrome seems to think WebGL is unavailable. That's not addressed in the other question.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try overriding it: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ou3H55QuO8U

Comment: @MC10 I tried enabling `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist` to override it, but nothing changed :(

Comment: Someone here http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu with the same card suggested `I have a workaround: Turn on "Disable accelerated 2D canvas" option in chrome://flags/`.

Comment: @MC10 Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Have you updated to the latest drivers available for your graphics card? Are you on a reasonably modern operating system?

Comment: @Mokubai It seems it may be the OS. I have WinXP. I have tried booting into Lubuntu, and if I enable hardware acceleration it works.

Comment: Yeah, it may no longer be supported in Windows XP: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Uw_ZJwQseKw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPU rendering has been removed in XP, so theoretically it's not possible to have WebGL.

WebGL worked in [build 291943](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/291943/) (v39.0.2138.0), but was removed in [build 291976](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/291976/) (v39.0.2138.0).

The [changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/c6827dc145d3e511e674fb5fcce9f5785dd2185e..2506984b8897fb85e84145a4e7e1bba220c33806?n=1000) contains the culprit [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/247f9ff7d967f161ff96afc68b82aeb78a6fa4b3):

> Remove the use of d3dcompiler_43.dll.
>   It was only used for GPU rendering on Windows XP, which is now
>   blacklisted.
>   [BUG=407177](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407177)
>   Review URL: https://codereview.chromium.org/506633002

Effectively, build 291976 only contains `d3dcompiler_46.dll`, but not `d3dcompiler_43.dll`.

So I had a crazy idea:

1. Install a new version of Chromium (with no WebGL)
2. Replace its `d3dcompiler_46.dll` file with `d3dcompiler_43.dll` from [build 291943](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-continuous/o/Win%2F291943%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1409101127502000&alt=media)

   This enables WebGL until [build 297440](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/297440/) (v40.0.2175.0).

   However, it stops working again since [build 297795](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/297795/) (version 40.0.2176.0).

   I looked at the [changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/dd79158782326a3ee31ec772c3c8a8bba81d53ff..c2401a37a0ba385317e71cb430356458328a12df?n=1000) but couldn't find the culprit commit.
3. Replace its `libGLESv2.dll` file with `libGLESv2.dll` from [build 297440](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-continuous/o/Win%2F297440%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1412119952627000&alt=media)

   This enables WebGL until [build 303843](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-continuous/o/Win%2F303843%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1415825384317000&alt=media) (v41.0.2219.0).

   However, it stops working again since [build 303851](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/303851/) (v41.0.2219.0).

   Given [this changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/9d145aaa93ef3142508635858904102784d0ba5f..e3195e972cc9a4618accf7ce8fbeeee4f327f810?n=1000), the culprit seems [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/ea03869066b9c0352fed76722b8f236daaf80dd2).
4. Replace its `libEGL.dll` file with `libEGL.dll` from [build 303843](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-continuous/o/Win%2F303843%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1415825384317000&alt=media)

   This enables WebGL until [build 337003](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/337003/) (v45.0.2446.0).

   However, it stops working again since [build 337025](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Win/337025/) (v45.0.2446.0).

   I looked at the [this changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/9786cc28c49d9b0637daf1cdcced0aacbc26b93f..0f3065e95a54f3b244cb30f7058d60ddf299f423?n=1000) but couldn't find the culprit commit.
5. WebGL can be enabled again in build 337025 by replacing `chrome.dll`, `chrome.exe`, `chrome_child.dll`, `natives_blob.bin` and `snapshot_blob.bin` from build 337003.

   However, that seems too much. I don't recommend it.

**Warning**: doing any of the steps above might make Chromium behave unreliably. Use at own risk.

In the steps above, "replace `[X].dll` with `[Y].dll` from `build [N]`" means:

1. Search the `[X].dll` file in the installation folder of Chromium
2. If there is no such file, go to step 4
3. Otherwise, rename the file to `[X].backup.dll`
4. Download the portable (ZIP) version of the linked `build [N]`
5. Extract the `[Y].dll` file from the downloaded ZIP
6. Rename the extracted file to `[X].dll`
7. Move that file to the installation folder of Chromium

Comment: how about windows 7 ?

Comment: @Dariush I think Chrome is supposed to support WebGL on win7, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

d3dcompiler_46.dll and d3dcompiler_47.dll can easily work on XP using BlackWingCat's unofficial update KB2584577.

Google this:
WindowsXP-KB2584577-v0.4-x86-ENU.exe

Also we can use WineD3D wrapper to wrap Direct3D9Ex to enable Chrome HW accel for XP.

Comment: Interesting, but I have updated to Win10, so I can't test. I think Chrome no longer supports XP anyways.

Comment: This is that what MSFT and Google wanted from you, I think this is unfair.