# Fix WebGL on Windows XP and Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, graphics, webgl

Can you fix Windows XP to use WebGL?

The photo editing sites on the browser no longer work  (ipiccy-pixlr), for a few months before everything ok

[image: screenshot]

Can you fix it by changing something in Firefox for this WebGL error?

I forced WebGL to run on the browser on about: config and set webgl.force-enabled to true but the error persists.

Is there any solution?

[image: screenshot]

about:config (webgl properties):

```
webgl.can-lose-context-in-foreground;true
webgl.default-no-alpha;false
webgl.disable-extensions;false
webgl.disabled;false
webgl.enable-draft-extensions;false
webgl.force-enabled;true
webgl.force-layers-readback;false
webgl.lose-context-on-heap-minimize;false
webgl.max-warnings-per-context;32
webgl.min_capability_mode;false
webgl.msaa-force;false
webgl.prefer-16bpp;false
webgl.prefer-native-gl;false
webgl.shader_validator;true
```

Anyone who still uses a Windows XP would like to solve this problem so the answers are well appreciated for the community.

Error caused a few months by updates of photo editing sites we do not know why they have always gone well but in this way they make a PC unusable. Canva also seems to me to no longer work on XP.

Your previous discussion at this address:

[How to enable WebGL on Chrome on XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/958238/how-to-enable-webgl-on-chrome-on-xp)

indicates solutions on the chrome browser and not on Firefox. I would only be interested in Firefox.

Latest changes on about:config

```
Webgl.disable-angle False (default) -> True
```

but still no results.

[image: screenshot]

No photo editing works

[image: screenshot]

Comment: _"anyone of you who still uses a win xp would like to solve this problem"_ - nobody should be using XP since at least 2014. That's the problem.

Comment: The previous question gives an indication on eighth notes but not on firefox ... I'm interested in how to solve on firefox.

Comment: There's apparently a `disable_angle` setting to change as well: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1247880

Comment: What is your graphics card and driver version? https://www.sitepoint.com/firefox-enable-webgl-blacklisted-graphics-card/

Comment: I don't have a dedicated video card installed.

Comment: I also tried with other browsers but it doesn't work with them either