# How to check if my computer hardware supports WebGL?

Tags: google-chrome, compatibility, webgl

From what I've read online ([How can I enable WebGL in my browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL)), WebGL is browser dependent. However, even after following the instructions in the above SuperUser question, [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/) says my *computer* doesn't support WebGL. How do I confirm that it's actually my computer hardware, and not the software that doesn't support WebGL?

For reference, I'm using a 2011 MacBook Air with integrated graphics (Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB), and the latest version of the Chrome Browser (Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)).

Comment: You have to determine what version of OpenGL/WebGL your GPU   supports to determine this.  Your GPU supports OpenGL 3.1 and 4.0.  So have you verified your Chrome installation has WebGL enabled?  Since your GPU supports OpenGL 3.1 and OpenGL 4.0 it has support for WebGL, because WebGL, required OpenGL 2.0 support.  Sounds like a case of not having the required display drivers and your GPU is defaulting to pre-OpenGL 2 support

Comment: I determined what version(s) of OpenGLyour GPU supports by doing a google search on the `name of your GPU plus OpenGL` by the way.  The information is also documented by Intel/Nvidia/AMD just found it easier to do a google search