# WebGL intermittently disabled on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, webgl

I'm trying to view 3D models using WebGL at [SketchFab](https://sketchfab.com/) in Google Chrome, but an error states that 3D is not available.  I've followed [instructions to enable WebGL](https://superuser.com/a/836833); I've updated my graphics drivers and ignored browser blocklists.

Now here's the strange thing: Sometimes WebGL works, and sometimes it doesn't.  In one browsing session, it stopped working, then perhaps ten minutes later worked again – without my changing any settings.  https://get.webgl.org/ always tells me that my browser supports WebGL, making me wonder whether this issue might be specific to SketchFab.

What could be causing this behaviour?

#### Technical details

I'm running Google Chrome 87.0.4280.141 on Windows 10 OS Version 2009 (Build 19042.746), with flags
`--enable-webgl-draft-extensions` `--enable-webgl2-compute-context` `--ignore-gpu-blocklist`

`chrome://gpu` reports Graphics Feature Status: "WebGL: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable", with "Problems Detected: Gpu compositing has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line. The browser will fall back to software compositing and hardware acceleration will be unavailable.
Disabled Features: gpu_compositing"

I haven't encountered the error in Firefox 82.0.2.